# Exception on Spring integration, when shut down the tomcat server

Tags: java, jms, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration application which runs on Tomcat 6. It has a `message-driven-channel-adapter` and it communicates with remote Active MQ server. So far so good I am able to do my work.

However when I shut down Tomcat I am getting the following exception endlessly looping in the catalina log:

```
Exception in thread   "org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-178" Exception in thread "org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-179" 

 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:188)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.trace(Log4JLogger.java:166)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.closeMessageConsumer(JmsUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.clearResources(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:971)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:188)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.trace(Log4JLogger.java:166)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.closeSession(JmsUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.clearResources(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1112)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:971)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Nov 13, 2012 7:23:37 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.log4j.spi.VectorWriter.  The eventual following stack trace is ca
used by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1273)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:154)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:853)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.warn(Log4JLogger.java:234)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerSetupFailure(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:831)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:981)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Do you guys have any idea bout this? do i need to close or destroy Spring context before I shut down Tomcat?

Appreciate your help

Thanks,
Keth

Comment: Are you directly or indirectly using apache velocity?
How many applications are hosted on this tomcat?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the question about Velocity?

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like you are correct:

> do i need to close or destroy Spring context before I shut down Tomcat?

From Spring JSM source code it looks like your Tomcat closes its **log4j.LogManager** earlier, than Spring stops its context.